# Android Studio: How can I edit colors.xml while displaying a Preview of activity_main.xml?

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, colors, resources

I'm new to Android programming and still getting used to Android Studio. I have created both my **activity_main.xml** and **colors.xml** files. And I have set the colors of various UI elements to use the resource colors (eg, **android:background="@color/myBackground"**).

The problem is that when I'm editing colors.xml, I can't see the Preview for activity_main.xml and switching between them is annoying.

Is there any way to keep the Preview open while editing colors.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot keep two previews open. Each .xml has or not it's own kind of preview. If you really don't want to swith that much, you could add the hardcoded color(s) to  `android:background="#000000"` for eg., and see how it looks or change it as many times as you want, than you can add it to colors.xml

Comment: Thanks for the response! I thought that was how it works but was hoping there was a way to do it. Using hard-coded colors is a good tip. :)